# How to create a multidimensional CGPoint array?

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, cgpoint

I want to have a 6 by 6 multidimensional array of CGpoints which will hold the vertex locations of 6 horizontal and 6 vertical lines. How would i do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you're encountering a problem. Is there something preventing you from writing `CGPoint vertexLocations[6][6];`?

Comment: Wow I didn't know it could be done so simply, thanks! My professor told me I needed to do something like the guy who answered, but this seems to work perfect, well at least so far the complier didn't complain.

Comment: @user3474512 Chuck's answer works just as well. They're very different approaches, though. One is a C-style array, whereas NSArray is an Objective-C object.

Comment: The way you did seems to use both C and objective C, because CGPoint is objective-c but the way you made the array is how it is made in C or C++ correct?

Comment: @user3474512: You mean me? Well, it's not really mixing anything. C is part of Objective-C — like, literally, any C program is also an Objective-C program. But yes, that's how you'd write it in plain C, where we don't have NSArrays and NSValues.

Comment: @Chuck Cool, one last question how would I make vertexLocations[6][6]; a global variable? The compiler screams at me when I try to do Property CGPoint vertextArray[][]; or Property CGPoint vertextArray[6][6]; I got the method to do what i needed, and the Multi D array has my values, but I have no way of accessing it out of the method. I tried returning it, but the compiler yelled at me again. Any suggestions? Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use NSArrays to do this, it would look something like the following:

```
NSMutableArray* topLevelArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    NSMutableArray* innerArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [topLevelArray addObject:innerArray];
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(x, y);
        [innerArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
    }
}
```

Then, to access a point from your array:

```
CGPoint point = [topLevelArray[i][j] CGPointValue];
```

Comment: Pretty sure i can work with this, thanks for your help!